# Question on Newton's law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I have heard my friends referring to quantity ma as the "force of acceleration" whereas my teacher told us it can't be referred as so. Is it correct to refer that quantity a force? If not, how can we better describe this quantity?

Comment: All acceleration is due to some force. The quantity $ma$ represents the Force, as given by Newton's 2nd law. I have never heard the phrase 'force of acceleration', since all acceleration arises from a net force.

Comment: $F$ is force. $ma$ is the same thing. $a$ is acceleration.

Comment: It's wrong to say "force of acceleration" but correct to simply say "force".  I imagine this is what your teacher was getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call it inertial force, but to be exact it should be called the *rate of momentum change*.

$$ \vec{F} = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} ( m \vec{v}) = m \vec{a} $$